# Laravel: NotFoundHttpException

Tags: laravel, homestead

I have problems when trying to go to the "http://homestead.app/videos"
There are my routes

```
//Video Area
Route::get('video', function() {
    return view('pages.videos');
});
Route::any('video/{id?}', ['as' => 'video', 'uses' => 'VideoController@showVideo'])
    ->where('id', '^[0-9]*$');

Route::resource('video', 'VideoController');
```

Comment: You have no `/videos` (plural) route defined; only `/video` (singular).

Comment: Solved.. there was the problem in *s* word. It must be *http://homestead.app/video* instead of *http://homestead.app/videos*. 
Thanks!